# Pure REST API Service with Spring Boot (no resources, no favicon, no webjars, ...)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm developing a REST API backend with Spring Boot for a single page application (Angular).

There's a lot of magic happening under the hood of Spring Boot which I don't understand yet. To achieve better security ("hardening"), I don't want Spring to install any superfluous service handlers used by Spring MVC or the like. Only REST endpoints consuming and producing JSON, no error-routes, no favicon.ico, etc. There is no static content (SPA is delivered by nginx and is a separate deployment unit).

During start the logging looks like this:

```
[19:04:06.146] INFO  andler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [main]: Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[19:04:06.146] INFO  andler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [main]: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[19:04:06.190] INFO  andler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [main]: Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

How can I configure my application to exclusively serving the API endpoints and nothing else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, spring boot does a lot of auto configuration under the hood. And usually the best place to start your search is documentation [Appendix A](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). At least for me it feels so natural and easy to follow for most of the cases. You can probably solve your problem with  `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false    # Disable resolution of favicon.ico.
spring.resources.add-mappings=false # Disable default resource handling.
```

Btw, if it is not enough, most of the time there are also links to the source code of configuration classes. So you can override them if you actually need more complicated tuning.

Comment: Many thanks. Exactly what I wanted - with least impact. API still works :-)